# catch notification of explode()

Tags: php, string, explode, string-matching

I process input of users.

Input should have this format:

```
text. address: xyz
```

Now I tried to use:

```
$address = explode('address: ', $text)[1];
```

But this causes an error in case of user input doesn't match the needed format.

How do I prevent this (maybe including a check), so script won't trigger a notice?

Comment: Validate that value *before* you act upon it

Comment: this seems closely related to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/38796925/ where a comment was left with that same exact syntax. *`explode(' address: ', $str)[1]`? – Casimir et Hippolyte 2 days ago* - which I might add you've gotten answers for. So who knows where that one stands.

Comment: Shouldn't have used `explode` for string extraction in the first place. That's what regexps are more suited for.

Comment: @JohnConde It's just going one ear and out the other John, *classic case*. And this smells like a repost, as per my comment up there. Moving on now... enjoy your day ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First assign variable:

```
$address = explode("address: ", $text);
```

Then check if is set key `1`:

```
if (isset($address[1]) {
    $address = $address[1];
}
```

Then you shouldn't have any notices because next time you'll to existing parameter in array.